# Browsers behave differently after 'submit' form is exectuted

Tags: javascript, html

I've got very simple example:

```
<html> 
<head> 

 <title> Addition</title> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    document.write("Please enter values to be added into the fields and click Add button1");


function sum() 
{     
     var num1 = document.formOne; 
     value1 = Number(num1.input1.value); 

     var num2 = document.formOne; 
     value2 = Number(num2.input2.value);   

  if (value1=="")
    { 
       document.write("Valid value cannot be empty!"); 

    }
  else if(value2=="")
    { 
        document.write("Valid value cannot be empty!"); 

    }
    else 
    { 
       var add = value1 + value2;    
       document.write ("The sum is " + add );     
    } 

 return true;
}

</script> 
</head> 

<body> 

<form id="forma" name="formOne" runat="server" onsubmit="sum()">
    <p><input id="Textone" name="input1" type="text" size="8"></p> 
    <p><input id="Texttwo" name="input2" type="text" size="8"></p> 
    <p><input type="submit" value="Add"> </p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

In IE after 'Add' is clicked the answer is given, but page will not reload on F5. To reload I need to hit 'back'.  In Chrome answer flashes, but page goes back to start.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ Using `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the form to follow through an submit the data back to the server, your `onsubmit` parameter should return false.

```
function sum() 
{     
  var num1 = document.formOne; 
  value1 = Number(num1.input1.value); 

  var num2 = document.formOne; 
  value2 = Number(num2.input2.value);   

  if (value1=="")
  { 
    document.write("Valid value cannot be empty!"); 

  }
  else if(value2=="")
  { 
    document.write("Valid value cannot be empty!"); 

  }
  else 
  { 
    var add = value1 + value2;    
    document.write ("The sum is " + add );     
  } 


  return false; // Changed to "false"
}
```

You also need to tweak the HTML so that the value from `sum()` is actually *returned* to the `onsubmit` handler.

```
<form id="forma" name="formOne" runat="server" onsubmit="return sum();">
```

Comment: Great!!! that solved Chrome problem, thank you.  Now, the only diff is that IE will not reload page (need to use 'back' to enter new values) and Chrome reloads just fine.  Thanks again.